# asyncfileupload inside update panel not triggering the upload method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am having a `asyncfileupload` inside a update panel, I want to upload the file once when a file is selected , the same code works well outside the update panel but my design is in such a way that I can put this outside the update panel, how can I make this work

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_DDL" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" Visible="true"
                    RenderMode="Inline">
      <ContentTemplate>  
   <asp:asyncfileupload id="AFU_Doc" runat="server"
     uploadingbackcolor="Yellow" onuploadedcomplete="btnDocUpload_Click"
      onclientuploadcomplete="sa" throbberid="spanUploading2" />
       <span id="spanUploading2" runat="server">Uploading...</span>
      </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AFU_Doc" />
         </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: add the fileupload to the triggers as an async trigger

Comment: I tried that even that didnt work    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AFU_Doc" />

Comment: Or put the async trigger on a button, the fact is that the file upload needs a full postback (which is the reason for the trigger) to work that's what makes it somewhat hard to combine with ajax